# How to add middleware to shopify app routes?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, shopify

Creating a shopify app with express and mongoose. The shop's domain and access tokens are saved to the database on the callback route of the install process. The index of the app is verified with the following function:

```
const verifyOAuth = query => {
    if (!query.hmac) {
        return false;
    }

    const hmac = query.hmac; 
    delete query.hmac;
    const sortedQuery = Object.keys(query).map(key => `${key}=${Array(query[key]).join(',')}`).sort().join('&');
    const calculatedSignature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', config.SHOPIFY_SHARED_SECRET).update(sortedQuery).digest('hex');
    if (calculatedSignature === hmac) {
      return true;
    }

  return false;
}
```

How can I create a middleware function for a request to access a shop's data from the mongo database. 
EX:

```
router.get('/content', auth, (req, res) => {
  const content = Content.findOne({shopifyDomain: 'shopify-domain-here'})
  res.send(content);
});

var auth = (req, res, next) => {
    // Get shop domain from authentication
    next();
};
```

Would I have to add the shop domain and hmac as a query for every get request to '/content', or should I use res.setHeader to set them as headers when the index of the app is loaded, or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add routes to Shopify. You will never have a request come to you from /Content. You obviously can make that a route in your own App though, and service that route.

If you want to sent content to Shopify, you should use the App Proxy. You receive a request for content, and then you fulfill that request with content formatted as Liquid or as JSON for example.

Comment: Not trying to add routes to shopify. The '/content' route is for my own app. The question was how can you add an express middleware function to verify what store app admin the request came from.

Comment: @KevinMangal were you able to solve this issue?